# Error al crear el control Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

Tengo un proyecto que no me carga los controles de telerik, ya instale la ultima versión pero mis controles aparece un mensaje error al crear el control, ¿a alguien le ha pasado que no puedan visualizar sus controles de telerik y como lo resolvieron?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste con la versión especifica 2017?

Comment: @DiegoCórdova la 2017 no la probe por que no la encontre, pero descargue la ultima version y agregue controles de esa version pero me arroja el mismo mensaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, segui el siguiente proceso: Se instala la nueva versión de telerik y en mi proyecto se agregan las referencias a Telerik.Web.UI.dll y Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll dando clic en examinar ubicamos las dll en la ruta donde se instalo telerik y se agregan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente se inicia visual studio y en el menu 'Telerik', seleccione la opcion de Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX y se selecciona Configurar proyecto y se da siguiente hasta finalizar y ya me aparecen los controles Telerik

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]